# How to know when user redirect output from erlang shell into a file

Tags: erlang

I have an sample module

```
    -module(helloworld).
    -compile(export_all).

    main() -> io:format("~s~s~s~n",["\e[31m","Hello world!","\e[0m"]).
```

When I build:

```
erlc helloworld.erl
```

After that, I run:

```
erl -noshell -s helloworld main -s init stop
Hello world! (with red color)
```

```
 
erl -noshell -s helloworld main -s init stop > text.txt
^[[31mHello world!^[[0m (The content in text.txt is ugly, so I don't like).
```

My problem is:

1. How to know when user redirect output from erlang shell into a file?
2. How can I write to text.txt the content just "Hello world!" not "^[[31mHello world!^[[0m"

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/init.html#get_arguments-0, you can check for the existence of "noshell" flag there an adopt output accordingly.

`[{root,["/opt/local/lib/erlang"]},{progname,["erl"]},{home,["/Users/..."]},{noshell,[]}]]},{helloworld,main,0},{init,start_it,1},{init,start_em,1}]`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `io:rows/0` that returns `{ok, Number}` if it is a terminal or `{error, enotsup}` if it is not.  More information [here](http://erlang.org/doc/man/io.html#rows-0).

Answer (score -3):

Thanks, but I don't think that can solve my problem.
I use isatty in C library and solved it.

Comment: You should write this as a COMMENT not as an ANSWER.